# Generic `getText()` function for UI elements in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-extensions

For a lot of actions, I need to check if the content of `label.text`, `textView.text`, `textField.text` etc. is nil.

So I created some extensions:

```
extension UILabel {
    func getText() -> String {
        return self.text ?? ""
    }
}

extension UITextField {
    func getText() -> String {
        return self.text ?? ""
    }
}

extension UITextView {
    func getText() -> String {
        return self.text ?? ""
    }
}
```

The extensions are very redundant. A similar case is when I need to cast an `Int`, `Double`, `Float` etc. to another number format. What I want is a simple `toInt()` with a return of `-1` or `0` when something went wrong.

So how can I create a generic function for the `toString()` or `toInt()`? I read about [extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) and [generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html) in the Apple documentation, but I didn't see a solution for my problem.

Finally, I tried to expand `UIView` with the same extension, because it's a superclass of `UILabel` etc., but I can't call `getText()`.

So what is a good method to create generic extensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of dubious things here: I wouldn't want any `toInt()` function to just return -1 or 0 when things went wrong. Swift has a good optionality system for a reason, and there are several obvious pitfalls introduced by returning -1 or 0. I also don't know what you plan to do for implementing `getText()` on a `UIView`. Lots of views don't have text. I don't know what this implementation would mean or do.

So I'll ignore those two details and focus on the primary question, which seems to be the redundancy of your extensions. There is a cleaner way, via protocol extensions, to cut down on duplication.

```
protocol TextProviding {
    var text: String? { get }
}

extension TextProviding {
    // Following your example here. I would prefer calling
    // this a `var textOrEmpty: String` but same idea.
    func getText() -> String {
        return text ?? ""
    }
}

// To conform additional types, you just need 1 line
extension UILabel: TextProviding { }
extension UITextField: TextProviding { }
```

**EDIT**: as some have pointed out, using the above code with `extension UITextView: TextProviding { }` will not work, because `UITextView`'s `text` is a `String!`, not a `String?`. Unfortunately, this means if you want this to work for UITextView as well, you should rename the `var text` requirement to something else (and this means you will need a couple extra lines to manually conform `UILabel` and `UITextField`).

```
protocol TextProviding {
    var string: String? { get }
}

extension TextProviding {
    var stringOrEmpty: String {
        return string ?? ""
    }
}

extension UILabel: TextProviding { 
    var string: String? { return text }
}
extension UITextField: TextProviding { 
    var string: String? { return text }
}
extension UITextView: TextProviding {
    var string: String? { return text }
}
```

Comment: I've noticed you've omitted `UITextView`. Isn't it because `text` there is `String!` instead of `String?`?

Comment: Nope just missed it in the original example. Should work fine too.

Comment: but it doesn't work for `UITextView` for the reason I've put above.

Comment: I use this extension in almost all my code, and it's a very good one. I recommend, however, calling the property `string` rather that using a method called `getText()`. It matches the `.stringValue` pattern from macOS, and is more natural as a property than a method.

Comment: As mentioned above, `extension UITextView: TextProviding { }` does not compile. For some reason, Apple has chosen to make `text` a `String?` property for some classes, and a `String!` property for other classes.

Comment: Huh, I thought I remembered the compiler being able to handle the mismatch between actual optional and UITextView's implicitly unwrapped optional. Guess not. I'll edit

Comment: @MartinR, and something tells me the problem is that there's no nullability attribute in the `Objective C` code for `UITextView`. Is there any radar reported about it?

Comment: @RobNapier what's your preferred name for the nil-coalesced version? `stringOrEmpty` etc?

Comment: Playing devil's advocate: What is the advantage of defining `var string: String? { return text }` properties for each class, a protocol, and a protocol extension, over the original approach of defining a function/property `var string: String { return text ?? "" }`  for each class?

Comment: @MartinR agreed. At that point, it just consolidates the nil coalescing logic so you'd repeat yourself slightly less when adding a new class to conform. I don't usually make an extension for this, but if I were to, I'd probably throw away UITextView and go with the first example.

Comment: @user28434: `UITextView` declares `@property(null_resettable,nonatomic,copy) NSString *text;` in Objective-C, which indicates a property which can be set to `nil`, but whose getter will never return `nil` (from http://nshipster.com/swift-1.2/). As far as I know, the same is true for `UITextView` and probably also `UILabel`. So it is the other way around: All those properties should be `null_resettable` in Objective-C, and `String!` in Swift. (I am sure this has been discussed somewhere before.) – But anyway: Filing (another) bug about this inconsistency would do no harm!

Comment: @Connor My `string` is just as Martin says: `var string: String { return text ?? "" }`. There's no point to a `stringOrEmpty`. "" is a string.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, you should only extend `UIView` and check whether its a label, a text field or a text view with `if let`.

```
extension UIView {
    func getText() -> String {
        if let label = self as? UILabel {
            return label.text ?? ""
        } else if let textField = self as? UITextField {
            return textField.text ?? ""
        } else if let textView = self as? UITextView {
            return textView.text ?? ""
        }

        return ""
    }
}
```

The advantage of this method over creating a protocol is that you can easily extend it, even if the text/title is retrievable with another method, for example, with a `UIButton`.

```
[...]
else if let button = self as? UIButton {
    return button.title(for: .normal) ?? ""
}
```

Comment: That's even worse than code in the question. Redundancy level is same, but now it's not even extendable.

Comment: A disadvantage is that `someView.getText()` compiles for instances of *any* `UIView` subclass, even those which have to text content.

Comment: @MartinR That can be an advantage in a situation where you iterate through a bunch of `UIView`s and only want to get a non-empty value for the ones which have a text/title.

Answer (score 0):

This **one-liner** reduces redundant code *(what you wanted)* than all other answers posted here. No need for crazy condition-checks or multiple extensions.

```swift
extension UIView {
    func getText() -> String? {
        return self.responds(to: #selector(getter: UILabel.text)) ?
        self.perform(#selector(getter: UILabel.text))?.takeUnretainedValue() as? String : nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a protocol with an extension and then extend every class to adopt the protocol :)

```
protocol GetTextProtocol {
    var text: String? {get}
    func getText() -> String
}

extension GetTextProtocol {
    func getText() -> String {
        return self.text ?? ""
    }
}

extension UILabel: GetTextProtocol {
    var text: String? {
         return self.text
    }
}
extension UITextView: GetTextProtocol {
    var text: String? {
        return self.text
    }    
}
```

Comment: Couple of problems here. I assume `extension getText` is a typo for `extension GetTextProtocol`, but unless you declare in the protocol `var text: String? { get }`, the extension won't work anyway. Third, if you supply `var text: String? { get }`, there's no reason to declare `func getText()` in the actual protocol.

Comment: That won't even compile.

Comment: True, I am going to fix

Comment: Fixed :), @Connor I have just seen your answer hahahaha both posted at the same time hahahaha. P.D: In your code there is a problem too, you need to include stringOrEmpty in the protocol.

Comment: @PabloSanchezGomez nope, you don't. That has an entirely different meaning.